# Where to put Grant_Type in XHR

Tags: javascript, typescript, paypal, xmlhttprequest, nativescript

I tried to access my OAuth2 Token via XHR-Request in TypeScript. I keep getting either 400: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Grant Type is NULL"}

I am making my call via a NativeScript Application (in TypeScript Template) running on an iOS emulator.

My code:

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    oReq.open("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", true);
  //  oReq.withCredentials = true;
  //  oReq.setRequestHeader('grant_type', "client_credentials");
  // where client_credentials = clientID:secret 

    oReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " + this.authorizationBasic); 
//where AutorizationBasic is the base64 String of my credentials
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', "en_US");

    oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("state changed - new state: " + oReq.readyState + " and Status: " + oReq.status);
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {
                console.log(oReq.responseText);
            } else { 
                console.log("Error: " + oReq.status + " Message: " + oReq.responseText);
            } 
        }    
    };
    console.log("Status: " + oReq.status);  
    oReq.send();
```

After doing some research I found out, that some others had the same issue with the PayPal API (e.g. [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/356)). Did someone solve that issue? Is it perhaps my code that is just wrong? In the code above I commented some other things that I tried, nothing seems to work.

The API: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

I am trying quite desperately since this is taking far too long to simple call that API. I tried the curl-command with my clientID + secret, which worked for me. Does anyone have an idea what to do? Is there perhaps an easier way than using XHR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else is searching for this:

You need to provide the Grant Type as the body in xhr.send()-Method:

```
xhr.send('grant_type=client_credentials');
```